# Loader<Cursor> Error on LoaderManager when using Support Library

Tags: loader

Why do I get this error?

> (Error:(42, 107) error:  is not
>   abstract and does not override abstract method
>   onCreateLoader(int,Bundle) in LoaderCallbacks)

While creating a music player app

Error continues to appear in Loader .

```
private void getAudioListFromMediaDatabase() {
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() {
        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            String[] projection = new String[]{
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
            };
            String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " = 1";
            String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
            return new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), uri, projection, selection, null, sortOrder);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> loader) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
            mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
        }


        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
            mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
        }
    });
}
```